# ng-select typeahead=true multiple=true pill remove script side is not working

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I used ng-select in my project.
It's worked perfectly.

But I have the empty label at removing the pill time. Like below

[image]

**Step to replicate:**

- Click the below stackblitz link
- Search & select two or more items in ng-select.
- Then click the above one blue pill for remove one item on the script side.

**[My stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-typeahead-when-search-cleared-repyrf?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

My code sample below

(template HTML code)

```
<div *ngFor="let data of selectTerm; index as assignedByIndex">
  <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-primary" style="cursor: pointer" (click)="removeSelect(selectTerm, assignedByIndex)">
      {{data.name}}
  </span>
</div>


<h5 class="mt-5">Select:</h5>
<ng-select *ngIf="showSelect" [items]="items$ | async" bindLabel="name" bindValue="id" (change)="select($event)"
  [closeOnSelect]="true" [(ngModel)]="selected" [multiple]="true" [hideSelected]="true" [typeahead]="input$">
</ng-select>
<h5>Typeahead:</h5>
<code #code></code>
```

(Script code)

```
  select(event) {
    this.selectTerm = event;
  }

  removeSelect(element, index) {
    element.splice(index, 1);
    this.selected.splice(index, 1);
    this.showSelect = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.showSelect = true;
    });
  }
```

If anyone has this solution Kindly share me!

Comment: Can you elborate your Problem further? Following your steps to replicate does not reproduce the bug for me

Comment: @EricKrg Kindly check out this loom: https://www.loom.com/share/343a4ba16e38494e8474f6db5408164e
I also need this solution. If you know, Kindly share here.